# Oracle Database link with error

Tags: oracle11g

I'm trying to create a database link form an Oracle server to another.
The command I'm using is:

```
 create public database link mylink connect to myuser identified by 0000 authenticated by myuser identified by 0000 using 'myTNSNameRemoteServer';
```

sqlplus give me this error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Putting the '*' under the first character of the password in its first instance.

Have I to escape it in someway?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error creating database link in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678877/error-creating-database-link-in-oracle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to double quote the password:

```
create public database link mylink connect to myuser identified by "0000" authenticated by myuser identified by "0000" using 'myTNSNameRemoteServer';
```

Comment: Even though there are another correct answers, this is the explicit one, so this should be marked as correct.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK "dblink_name"
             CONNECT TO "user_user"
             IDENTIFIED BY "user_pass"
             USING '(DESCRIPTION =
                (ADDRESS_LIST =
                  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = "user_server" )(PORT ="user_port" ))
                )
                (CONNECT_DATA =
                  (SERVICE_NAME = "user_service_name")
                  (SRVR = DEDICATED)
                )
              )' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: 
CREATE DATABASE LINK ABCD CONNECT TO USER IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD USING 'DBALIASAME';

Comment: I think that the problem is the password, that as you can see is a sequence of four 0 (number). What I wrote is not a fake password sadly.

Comment: @StefaniaLori I've tried to create a user with password '0000' and it doesn't allow to create at the first instance, so if you have any other user with you, could you please with that one else get your password reset to something else :)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the user password because it is a production database, but I tried the same db link with another user, with a simple password and it worked perfectly.

Comment: thats great, you got the solution finally :)