# Error creating database link in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two databases and need to write a cross database query. So I'm trying to create a database link.

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK DBLink CONNECT TO SchemaName IDENTIFIED BY 123 using 'DBName';
```

When I executing this query it's take following error "ORA - 00933:SQL command not properly ended". Can anybody explain me where is the mistake?

P.S. I'm using SQL Developer.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360258/oracle-database-link-with-error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually solve this problem. The problem was in the numbers used as password. To fix it use double quotes in password like this:

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK DBLink CONNECT TO SchemaName IDENTIFIED BY "123" using 'DBName';
```

Comment: I don't think so. In my case i have only letters as password.